# How to use SDWebImageManager to download image only if NOT already cached?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, sdwebimage

I need the completion handler functionality of SDWebImageManager (to set the downloaded or cached image black and white), so I'm using it instead of sd_setimage. My issue is that I can't figure out how to use SDWebImageManager to download OR get the cached version of the image. The image re-downloads each time a tableview cell is dequeued and reloaded. I tried setting options: SDWebImageDownloaderOptions.useNSURLCache, but to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Here's my code:

```
SDWebImageManager.shared().imageDownloader?.downloadImage(with:URL(string: imgURL), options: SDWebImageDownloaderOptions.useNSURLCache, progress: nil, completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) in 
   if image != nil {
      let beginImage = CIImage(image: image!)
      let blackNwhiteImg = beginImage?.applyingFilter("CIColorControls", withInputParameters: [kCIInputSaturationKey:0.0])
      let newImage = UIImage(ciImage: blackNwhiteImg!)
      cell.button.setImage(newImage, for: .normal)
   }
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updated answer for pulling from cache:

```
SDWebImageManager.shared().loadImage(with: URL?, options: SDWebImageOptions, progress: { (Int, Int, URL?) in
    code
}, completed: { (UIImage?, Data?, Error?, SDImageCacheType, Bool, URL?) in
    code
})
```

For reference sake, am including this screenshot that shows the comment XCode presents while entering the function:

[image]

Also, the comments included in the `SDWebImageManager` file:

```
/**
 * Downloads the image at the given URL if not present in cache or return the cached version otherwise.
 *
 * @param url            The URL to the image
 * @param options        A mask to specify options to use for this request
 * @param progressBlock  A block called while image is downloading
 *                       @note the progress block is executed on a background queue
 * @param completedBlock A block called when operation has been completed.
 *
 *   This parameter is required.
 * 
 *   This block has no return value and takes the requested UIImage as first parameter and the NSData representation as second parameter.
 *   In case of error the image parameter is nil and the third parameter may contain an NSError.
 *
 *   The forth parameter is an `SDImageCacheType` enum indicating if the image was retrieved from the local cache
 *   or from the memory cache or from the network.
 *
 *   The fith parameter is set to NO when the SDWebImageProgressiveDownload option is used and the image is
 *   downloading. This block is thus called repeatedly with a partial image. When image is fully downloaded, the
 *   block is called a last time with the full image and the last parameter set to YES.
 *
 *   The last parameter is the original image URL
 *
 * @return Returns an NSObject conforming to SDWebImageOperation. Should be an instance of SDWebImageDownloaderOperation
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. This behaves exactly the same as the code I posted. Seems to me that both your code and mine are accessing the same .downloadImage() function. Can you be more specific with your syntax? Are there options I'm not setting? I tried with and without options: SDWebImageDownloaderOptions.useNSURLCache. Thanks again.

Comment: Another detail of my situation is that I am noticing the image reload in dequeued tableview cells. But from what I understand of sdwebimage, the dequeued and reloaded cells should be seamlessly reloading with the cached image.

Comment: I'm printing the cacheType value within the completion block every time an image is loaded. It is nil every time. This seems to indicate that there is no image cached?

Comment: @DanielGrigsby Updated my answer, I pulled the code from the wrong section & updated accordingly and included some supporting documentation.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `SDWebImageManager.shared().cachedImageExists(for: imageUrl)` to know if an `URL` is cached

After that you can get the cacheKey with this method

```
let cacheKey = SDWebImageManager.shared().cacheKey(for: imageUrl)
```

Having the CacheKey you can call this method and in his closure you will get your cached image

```
SDWebImageManager.shared().imageCache.queryDiskCache(forKey: cacheKey, done: { (image, cacheType) in

                })
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. And then how do I get the cached image for that URL within the completion block? There isn't and 'image' value passed in as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very useful to know about the CacheKey. I think .loadImage is what I was looking for.